# ng-model checkbox with string value

Tags: angularjs

is it possible to edit directly in an input tag the value of the ng-Model if the latter is a string value ?

This is the JavaScript object:

```
fields: [
 {id: 5, 
  name: "boolean", 
  type: "BOOL", 
  value: "true"
}]
```

This is the html code

```
<input  class="" type="checkbox" ng-model="line.value" data-ng-checked="line.value"/>
```

The goal would be to directly edit the html tag without modifying the json file.

By avoiding having the following error message

> "Error: ngModel:nonassign
>   Non-Assignable Expression"

if you have a solution?

cordially

Comment: If you have some code causing an error, and you wonder why, post the code and ask why. Yes, it's possible. But that won't help you.

Comment: @JB Nizet re-read the question the problem is due to the fact that the value is a string and not a boolean. I ask if it is possible to change the string value in boolean directly in the ng-model

Comment: Don't use `ng-model` and `ng-checked` together. Use `ng-model` for two-way binding. Use `ng-checked` for one-way binding. Read [AngularJS input type=checkbox Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Comment: As you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/5ejbozkc/, using your code allows having a checkbox that doesn't cause the error you get. So, once again, if you want us to explain why you get this error, post a complete minimal example reproducing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use string values with a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="line.value"
       ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'" />
```

To use string literals, use single-quotes (`'`) inside double-quotes (`"`). Otherwise the AngularJS will parse them as a [Boolean type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Boolean_type).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS input type=checkbox Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)